# Hyperlinks cannot be clicked on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, clickable

i have a site i did for a friend using the theme KIN for wordpress as a base. The site is built on Wordpress and it's using AJAX to load all the pages, but the links although visible cannot be clicked! i don't really know why at all. Below is the site...

http://www.baudesigncreative.com

if you navigate to the keep in touch page, you will notice there are links to pages. Odd thing here as i can see the link on the status bar, but nothing happens when i click. Im not sure where to look to resolve this, can anyone offer any help?

thanks so much!

---

I found the link break to be from bau.js thanks to help from below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  var url = '';
  var currentOpen = '';

  var mousedown = false;
  var galleryMousedown = false;
  var mouseX = 0;
  var xdiff = 0;

  var movePercentage = 0;
  var toMove = 0;

  function randomQuotes() {
    $('body').append('<div id="bau-quotes-holder"></div>');
    $('#bau-quotes-holder').hide();

    var quotesUrl = 'http://baudesigncreative.com/quotes/';
    var quotesLength = 0;

    $('#bau-description').html('').hide();
    $('#bau-quotes-holder').load(quotesUrl + ' #page_content_wrapper', function() {
      $('#bau-quotes-holder').find('dt').each(function() {
        $('#bau-description').append('<img src="' + $('a', this).attr('href') + '" />');
        quotesLength++;
      });
      $('#bau-description img').hide();

      var randomized = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotesLength) + 1);

      $('#bau-description').show();
      $('#bau-description img:nth-child(' + randomized + ')').fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('#bau-quotes-holder').remove();
      });
    });
  }

  randomQuotes();

  function scrollers() {
    $('#bau-gallery').hover(function() {
      $('#bau-gallery-left').fadeIn(200);
      $('#bau-gallery-right').css('marginLeft', $('#galleryScrollbar').width() - '29').fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
      $('#bau-gallery-left').fadeOut(200);
      $('#bau-gallery-right').fadeOut(200);
    });

    var galleryLength = 0;    
    $('#bau-gallery-list').find('img').each(function() {
      galleryLength++;
    });

    var scrollbarWidth = parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbar').width()) - 20;
    var scrollbarToMove = 0;

    var isDown = false;
    var galleryLeft = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list').css('left'));
    var galleryWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list').width());
    var lastImgWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width()) + 2;

    toMove = Math.abs($('hr').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width());
    // var jumpWidth = ((galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove) / (galleryLength - 1)) / 20;
    var jumpWidth = ((galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove) / (galleryLength - 1)) / 2;

    // scrollbarToMove =  (scrollbarWidth / (galleryLength - 1)) / 20;
    scrollbarToMove =  (scrollbarWidth / (galleryLength - 1)) / 2;

    var timeoutLeft;
    var timeoutRight;

    $('#bau-gallery-left').dblclick(function(e) {
      return false;
    });

    $('#bau-gallery-right').dblclick(function(e) {
      return false;
    });

    $('#bau-gallery-left').click(function(e) {
      galleryWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list').width());
      lastImgWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width()) + 2;
      toMove = Math.abs($('hr').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width());
      jumpWidth = ((galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove) / (galleryLength - 1)) / 2;

      if ((galleryWidth - Math.abs(parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list').css('left')))) > galleryWidth - jumpWidth) {
        $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', 0);
        $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', 0);
      }
      else {
        $('#bau-gallery-list').animate({'left': '+=' + jumpWidth + 'px'}, 100);
        $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').animate({'left': '-=' + scrollbarToMove + 'px'}, 100);
      }

      return false;
    });

    $('#bau-gallery-right').click(function(e) {
      galleryWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list').width());
      lastImgWidth = parseFloat($('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width()) + 2;
      toMove = Math.abs($('hr').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width());
      jumpWidth = ((galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove) / (galleryLength - 1)) / 2;

      if ((scrollbarWidth - Math.abs(parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left')))) < scrollbarToMove) {
        $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', scrollbarWidth);
        $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', -(galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove));
      }
      else {
        $('#bau-gallery-list').animate({'left': '-=' + jumpWidth + 'px'}, 100);
        $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').animate({'left': '+=' + scrollbarToMove + 'px'}, 100);
      }

      return false;
    });

    //onhold
    // $('#bau-gallery-left').mousedown(function(e) {
      // if (!galleryMousedown) {
        // galleryMousedown = true;
        // timeoutLeft = setInterval(function() {
          // if ((scrollbarWidth - Math.abs(parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left')))) > scrollbarWidth - scrollbarToMove) {
            // $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', 0);
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', 0);
          // }
          // else {
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').animate({'left': '+=' + jumpWidth + 'px'}, 50);
            // $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').animate({'left': '-=' + scrollbarToMove + 'px'}, 50);
          // }
        // }, 50);
      // }

      // return false;
    // });

    // $('#bau-gallery-right').mousedown(function(e) {
      // if (!galleryMousedown) {
        // galleryMousedown = true;

        // timeoutRight = setInterval(function() {
          // if ((scrollbarWidth - Math.abs(parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left')))) < scrollbarToMove) {
            // $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', scrollbarWidth);
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', -(galleryWidth - lastImgWidth - toMove));
          // }
          // else {
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').animate({'left': '-=' + jumpWidth + 'px'}, 50);
            // $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').animate({'left': '+=' + scrollbarToMove + 'px'}, 50);
          // }
        // }, 50);
      // }        
      // return false;
    // });

    // $(window).mouseup(function(e) {
      // galleryMousedown = false;
      // clearInterval(timeoutLeft);
      // clearInterval(timeoutRight);

      // return false;
    // });
  }

  function backLoop() {
    $('#bau-gallery-back a').dblclick(function(e) {
      return false;
    });

    $('#bau-gallery-back a').click(function(e) {
      randomQuotes();
      var backShowcaseUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#bau-content').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#bau-gallery').remove();
        $('#bau-content').hide();
        $('#bau-content').append('<div id="page_content_wrapper"><div class="inner"><div id="bau-showcase"></div></div></div>')
        $('#bau-showcase').append($('#bau-showcase-holder').html());
        $('#bau-content').height('')
          .css('marginBottom', '')
          .width('')
          .css('overflow', '');
        $('#bau-content').fadeIn(500, function() {
          $('#bau-showcase-holder').remove();
          showcaseEvents();
        });
        $('#bau-content').height($('.inner').height());
      });

      return false;
    });
  }

  function showcaseEvents() {
    $('#bau-showcase li').dblclick(function(e) {
      return false;
    });

    $('#bau-showcase li').click(function(e) {
      randomQuotes();
      var showcaseUrl = $('a', this).attr('href');
      var tempWidth = 0;

      $('#bau-content').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#bau-showcase-holder').remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="bau-showcase-holder">' + $('#bau-showcase').html() + '</div>');
        $('#bau-showcase-holder').hide();

        $('#page_content_wrapper').remove();
        $('#bau-content').append('<div id="bau-gallery"></div>');

        $('#bau-gallery-holder').load(showcaseUrl + ' #page_content_wrapper', function() {
          $('#bau-gallery').append('<div id="bau-gallery-title">' + $('#bau-gallery-holder h2').text() + '</div><div id="bau-gallery-list"></div><div id="bau-gallery-left" class="scroller scroll-left"></div><div id="bau-gallery-right" class="scroller scroll-right"></div>')

          $('#bau-gallery-holder').find('dt').each(function() {
            var _thisImgUrl = $('a', this).attr('href');

            $('#bau-gallery-list').append('<img src="' + _thisImgUrl  + '"/>');
          });

          $('#bau-gallery').append('<div class="clear"></div><div id="galleryScrollbar"><div id="galleryScrollbarThumb"><img src="http://baudesigncreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/scrollbar_thumb.png" alt=""></div></div>')
            .append('<div id="bau-gallery-back"><a href="' + $('#main_menu li:nth-child(2) a').attr('href') + '"><img src="http://baudesigncreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/back-to-showcase.png" />Back to Showcase</a></div>');

          $('#bau-content').fadeIn(1000, function() {
            tempWidth = $('#bau-gallery').width();
            // $('#bau-gallery').width($('hr').width());
            $('#bau-content').width($('hr').width());
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').width($('#bau-gallery').width());
            // $('#bau-gallery-list').width($('hr').width());

            $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').mousedown(function(event) {
              if (!mousedown) {
                mousedown = true;
              }

              return false;
            });

            var scrollerOffset = $('hr').offset();
            var scrollerOffsetLeft = scrollerOffset.left;
            var realEvent = 0;

            $(window).mousemove(function(event) { 
              if (mousedown) {
                realEvent = event.pageX - (scrollerOffsetLeft + 10);

                if (realEvent < 0) {
                  realEvent = 0;
                }
                else if (realEvent > ($('hr').width() - 20)) {
                  realEvent = $('hr').width() - 20;
                }

                $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', realEvent);
                movePercentage = (realEvent) / ($('hr').width() - 20);
                toMove = Math.abs($('hr').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width());
                $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', -(movePercentage * ($('#bau-gallery-list').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width() - 2 - toMove)));
              }

              return false;
            });

            $(window).mouseup(function(event) { 
              mousedown = false;

              if (parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left')) <= 0) {
                $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', 0);
                $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', 0);
              }
              else if (parseFloat($('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left')) >= $('hr').width() - 20) {
                $('#galleryScrollbarThumb').css('left', $('hr').width() - 20);
                toMove = Math.abs($('hr').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width());
                $('#bau-gallery-list').css('left', -($('#bau-gallery-list').width() - $('#bau-gallery-list img:last-child').width() - 2 - toMove));
              }

              return false;
            });

            scrollers();

            backLoop();
          });

          $('#bau-content').height($('#bau-gallery').height())
            .css('marginBottom', $('#bau-gallery').css('marginBottom'))
            .width('100%')
            .css('overflow', 'hidden');

          $('#bau-gallery-back').width($('hr').width());
          $('#galleryScrollbar').width($('hr').width());

          $('#bau-gallery-holder').remove();
          $('body').prepend('<div id="bau-gallery-holder"></div>');
        });
      });

      return false;
    });
  }

  $('#page_content_wrapper').remove();
  $('#main_menu li:first').append('<div id="bau-ajax"><div id="bau-content"></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
  $('#bau-ajax').hide();

  $('body').prepend('<div id="bau-gallery-holder"></div>');
  $('#bau-gallery-holder').hide();

  $('#main_menu > li').dblclick(function(e) {
    return false;
  });

  $('#main_menu > li').click(function(e) {
    randomQuotes();
    $('#bau-showcase-holder').remove();
    var _this = $(this);
    var _thisA = $('a', this);

    $('#main_menu li a').css('color', '#000');
    $('#bau-content').slideUp(500, function() {
      if (_this.attr('id') != currentOpen) {
        $('#bau-ajax').remove();
        _this.append('<div id="bau-ajax"><hr><div id="bau-content"></div><div class="clear"></div><hr></div>');
        url = _thisA.attr('href');

        $('#bau-ajax').show();
        $('#bau-content').hide();
        _thisA.css('color', '#909295');

        $('#bau-content').load(url + ' #page_content_wrapper', function() {
          $('#bau-content h1').remove();
          $('#bau-content br').remove();

          $('#bau-content').fadeIn(500, function() {
            $('#bau-content').click(function(e) {
              return false;
            });

            showcaseEvents();
          });

          $('#bau-content').height($('.inner').height());
          currentOpen = _this.attr('id');
        });
      }
      else {
        $('#bau-ajax').remove();
        _this.append('<div id="bau-ajax"><div id="bau-content"></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
        url = _thisA.attr('href');
        currentOpen = '';
      }
    });

    return false;
  });  

  //styleSheets
  $('#menu_wrapper').css('width', '100%');
  $('#page_content_wrapper').css('width', '1000px');

});
```

Anyone by any chance spot anything that could be it?

when i comment out (from line 297)

```
$('#page_content_wrapper').remove();
```

it seems to remove the styling overlapping it which results it the page breaking a bit :(

am i missing something simple by any chance?

Comment: Only The links at "keep in touch" section is not working, right? all others are working fine at my end.

Comment: All the page content hyperlinks are not working, all the other pages do not have a link to another page so it works fine. So yeah just the Keep in touch section i cannot get the links to actually click. I feel its the AJAX and JS that is stopping the hyperlinks since it does so with the different pages maybe?

Comment: yes. Its the ajax that stopping the feature of hyperlink. I tried disabling all js and found the links are opening in a new tab.

Comment: is there anyway for me to find out which js file is causing the issue and if so, there is no way for me to have just page content to open links normally but not the other navigation such as switching between pages?

Comment: I don't know this solution will helpful to you or not. If you put your `keep in touch` links in footer, it will work.

Comment: It's your Javascript.  You've got two files (bau.js and custom.js) which are over riding the default browser behaviour for links so your sliding panels work.  Have a play around with them to remove the behaviour that's being applied to your links and restore the browser default.

Comment: ive been switching them off and on no luck yet :( - the guy that did the programming is refusing to change it and is charging me 200usd to fix this :(

Answer (score 0):

your link are working on my end if still you have problem with links then use CSS proerty.

```
Z-index:999;
```

Comment: does it open on a new window just fine? i cannot seem to get them to open on chrome :(

Comment: Just changed z-index from 200 to 999 but still no luck, im on a mac using chrome, safari and firefox neither work...

Comment: Hi, somewhere you use position:relative tag that consume please check via FIREBUG or something used in your mac, and find out the consumed space...